# How to split a string in angular 2

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have an email sending scenario in which there is an input box of 'To'(whom you want to send a message).

> app.html

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="email.Tos">
```

Now I want that when a user input the multiple emailId in input box by comma separated, then in my model,  'Tos' value should bind in an Array of string. 
Like : ["abc@gmail,com" , "xyz@gmail.com"].

Now, please tell me how to split the input box value as per my requirement.

Answer (score 20):

You need to use split() function.

**Component**

```
let toArray =  this.email.Tos.split(",");
```

variable toArray will contain an array of emails.

Please check [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)