# Loop json string in json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I want to get the values of each keyword:

```
var keyword = '{"coconut sugar", "healthy and natural sweetener", "low glycemic index sweetener"}';
```

[image]

To this:

```
coconut sugar
healthy and natural sweetener
low glycemic index sweetener
```

Comment: That's an invalid "`json object`". Use an array instead and join by `\n`

Comment: object contains key and value pair

Comment: You mean the keyword should be an array not object?

Comment: Please post code instead of or with the picture

Comment: this is array not json object

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863506/how-to-split-a-string-in-angular-2 `.split can also be used in the html`.

Comment: Okay I will fix my json object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an invalid "object". It is supposed to be an array with `[]`. If that's how your server is giving, you have to change the response there. In case, if you can't do that, you may parse it right in JavaScript.

```js
var keyword = '{"coconut sugar", "healthy and natural sweetener", "low glycemic index sweetener"}';
keyword = JSON.parse("[" + keyword.substr(1, keyword.length - 2) + "]");
console.log(keyword);

// After this use any array walker to process it.
for (var i = 0; i < keyword.length; i++)
  console.log(keyword[i]);
```