# how to get specific name before the character in fullpath in javascript?

Tags: angular

I have filenames in certificate_name variable, separated by "|".

```
For example:-
"e1412be6-3486-478a-a768-bc81b7ac40dd.jpg | Hydrangeas.jpg"
```

I want split the filename before | symbol.

Tried by using the below code, but it is not working. Could anyone please assist on this ?

```
   this.uploadedFiles.map(data => {
      data.certificate_name.substr(0,data.certificate_name.indexOf('|'));
      return data
 })
```

Comment: Have you tried split? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: "its [sic] not working" doesn't help anyone diagnose your issue. Do you get an error? What are you expecting? What are you getting instead? Also, please provide a [mre]; a piece of code people can run and reproduce the situation you are seeing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863506/how-to-split-a-string-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the `split` method which is used to split by given separator parameter. In your case it is Pipe '`|`'.

```
this.uploadedFiles.map(data => {
    const stringSplitToArray = data.certificate_name;
    const splitted = stringSplitToArray.split('|');
    console.log(splitted[0]);
    data.certificate_name = splitted[0];// need to add this line then only this solution works perfect
    return splitted[0];
});
```

The resultant data will consist of array of string as shown below.

```
splitted[0]= 'e1412be6-3486-478a-a768-bc81b7ac40dd.jpg'
splitted[1]= 'Hydrangeas.jpg'
```

From your question, I believe you want to retrieve only the first file name, I have gone with index 0.

Hope this help !!

Answer (score -1):

```
"e1412be6-3486-478a-a768-bc81b7ac40dd.jpg | Hydrangeas.jpg".split('|')
```